# Is the "Young Driver Surcharge" fee the same for all car rental companies in the UK?

Tags: uk, car-rentals, driving, automobiles, fees-and-charges

I am a 21 year old with almost 2 year old driving license. I'm going to the UK, and want to rent a car for several days, however when I searched for a rental car, I saw that 35-40 GBP were added as "Young Driver Surcharge" for each day. My question is, does this additional fee change from one rental company to other, or can I find a rental company that charges less for the same thing?

Comment: [This discussion on FlyerTalk's UK Forum](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/u-k-ireland/1587447-car-hire-u21s-waived-young-drivers-fee.html) has some information and suggestions, but no clear conclusion...

Answer (score 7):

No, these fees may vary, as may the age range they are applied for. Note also these change significantly between countries (and in some cases even between locations within a country).

Some of the main supplier's conditions in the UK:

```
Supplier   MinAge   Fee   NoFeeAge
```

```
Alamo        22     £27^     25
Avis         21     £45      25
Budget       23     £39"     25
Enterprise   25      ?       25°
Europcar     22     £31      25
Hertz        23     £31"     25
National     22     £27^     25
Sixt         21     £36      25*
Thrifty      21     £25"     25
```

"incl. tax - suppliers with no note may or may not be incl. tax

^excl. tax - suppliers with no note may or may not be incl. tax

°[Enterprise](https://www.enterprise.co.uk/car_rental/home.do) is not very clear; the selection form allows selecting age 18-24, but the terms say minimum age 25. Also the selection form returns an error saying 'some locations' may have age restrictions on all UK locations I have checked.

*Sixt is not consistent in what is says on it's site. [The Rental Guide](http://www.sixt.co.uk/rental-services/rental-guide/) says ages 21-23 will face the charge and mentions neither car classes on the amount payable, [the Rental Information](http://www.sixt.co.uk/rental-services/rental-information/) says all drivers below 25 pay £36 and lists a range of car classes which basically comprises all available for hire below the age of 25.

One additional note for the northern regions: [Arnold Clark](http://www.arnoldclarkrental.com/) rents cars without young driver surcharges in some locations - [T&C](http://www.arnoldclarkrental.com/terms-of-hire).

Here are links to the relevant pages of the mentioned suppliers - with the exception of Avis which does not allow direct linking to any useful page it seems: [Alamo](http://www.alamo.co.uk/helpfulinformation/gb)
[Budget](http://www.budget.co.uk/budget-UK/en_GB/products-services/additional-cover/young-driver-charges.html), [Europcar](http://www.europcar.co.uk/EBE/module/render/terms-and-conditions-specific-terms-per-country?countrySelector=termsandconditionsblocknewele-44), [Hertz](https://www.hertz.co.uk/rentacar/reservation/reviewmodifycancel/templates/rentalTerms.jsp?KEYWORD=AGE&EOAG=LGWT51), [National](http://www.nationalcar.co.uk/helpfulinformation/gb), [Thrifty](http://www.thrifty.co.uk/uk-booking-guide.htm)

Comment: Old answer, I know. But in the past I've managed to hire from Sixt (at age 24) without paying the fee.